# Word 2007: How to remove reminder about comments when saving?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

At my new job, the Enterprise IT folks appear to have enabled a reminder (presumably for security) when saving documents that contain comments. While this might be helpful for most, I use comments to note things in pre-production and I save often, so the dialog box comes up quite a bit.

My questions:

- Is this a group policy / administrative setting of some sort, or an application-specific setting that I can't find?
- Any idea how I can get rid of it?

An image of the dialog is below -- the "Tell me More" option appears to explain more about comments and not much about how to get rid of the dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this answer](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/119742-Prompts-to-save-comments) on Google:

> click the Office button, click Word options (at the very bottom of the menu), then click Trust Center. At the very bottom left of the page, click Trust Center Settings and then click Privacy Options at the left side of the page. Finally, uncheck "Warn before printing, saving or sending a file that contains tracked changes or comments" and OK out.

I hope it helps.